# How to get calculated ith element with its jith element (ij/sqrt(ii * jj) in matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix (80rows, 80columns), i am trying to calculate product of each ith * jth elements and divided by sqrt of ii * jj elements.
I am not getting any clue to provide an output.

```
a <- runif(100,0.0,1.0)
b <- matrix(a,10,10)
dput(b[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.232, 0.838, 0.488, 0.490, 0.799, 0.491, 0.424, 0.334, 0.399, 0.550, 0.835, 
0.784, 0.426, 0.643, 0.311,0.520, 0.670, 0.902, 0.992, 0.479, 0.737, 0.640, 0.547,0.011, 
0.166), dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

I Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: How is that going to work since your actual matrix will have only 80 elements on the diagonal but 5000 columns?

Comment: @dcarlson, my mistake, I've updated now.

Comment: Assuming that `d` is the 5x5 matrix you posted with dput, is this what you are looking for d[1, 1] `prod(d[1, ] * d[, 1])/d[1, 1]`?

Comment: @dcarlson, for example i need to calculate prod of two different element say d[1,2] and corresponding diagonal elements (d[1,1],d[2,2],) needed for its square root calculation.  such as d[1,2]/sqrt(d[1,1]*d[2,2]), d[1,3]/sqrt(d[1,1]*d[3,3]), d[1,4]/sqrt(d[1,1]*d[4,4]), d[1,5]/sqrt(d[1,1]*d[5,5])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you want. First the data:

```
d <- structure(c(0.232, 0.838, 0.488, 0.490, 0.799, 0.491, 0.424, 0.334,
     0.399, 0.550, 0.835, 0.784, 0.426, 0.643, 0.311,0.520, 0.670, 0.902,
     0.992, 0.479, 0.737, 0.640, 0.547,0.011, 0.166), dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

Now create matrices based on the diagonals:

```
drow <- matrix(diag(d), 5, 5)
dcol <- t(drow)
```

Finally compute the values and replace the diagonal values:

```
vals <- d/sqrt(drow * dcol)
diag(vals) <- diag(d)
# vals
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]       [,5]
# [1,] 0.232000 1.5655054 2.6560588 1.083936 3.75551457
# [2,] 2.671881 0.4240000 1.8447110 1.033085 2.41236490
# [3,] 1.552283 0.7858845 0.4260000 1.387541 2.05697249
# [4,] 1.021401 0.6152252 0.9891231 0.992000 0.02710708
# [5,] 4.071447 2.0731261 1.1695036 1.180390 0.16600000
```